# How to display progress bar while downloading from multiple URLs in Python

Tags: python, progress-bar

I've been writing a python script for downloading multiple files from GitHub(around 200 files). is there anyway to add common progress bar to display the progress of collective downloading. 
In simple terms, i need one common progress bar to display the downloading progress of all the 200 files.

Thanks,
Habeeb Ur Rehman

Comment: I would suggest adding a code example of what you have tried; why the thing that you tried didn't work for you, what may be an expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt show any code, but in case you are using a loop to go trough all your urls you can use the libary [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)

example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(len(urls)), ncols=90, desc="progress"):
    download(urls[i].files)
    ...
```

take a look on the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#documentation). I hope this helped you :)